# Deeplinking - Opening an Ionic App through another Ionic App

Tags: android, ios, cordova, ionic-framework, deep-linking

I'm trying to develope two Ionic applications which are apple to communicate at least in one direction. How do I enable one application to directly open the other one? I have red many things about Deep-Linking but I'm not sure if this is the right way as I only want to open one app (and maybe passing data) through the calling of a function within the other app.

Does anyone have experience with this scenario? I'm happy for every answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [Custom-URL-scheme](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/Custom-URL-scheme) plugin

Install it like this:

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-customurlscheme --variable URL_SCHEME=mycoolapp
```

Then in the other app install cordova-plugin-inappbrowser to open the first app like this:

```
window.open('mycoolapp://', '_system');
```

Then install the Custom-URL-scheme plugin in this app with a different variable and use above code with the different variable value to open the other app.

You can get the url (in case you also pass some params) like this:

```
function handleOpenURL(url) {
  console.log("received url: " + url);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used above code in my app, and thats working but newly opened app replacing the old one.
I have two apps called demo 1 AND demo2, and am opening demo2 from demo1 but after opening demo2 the demo1 is replacing with demo2.